# How do you have a user input a number and have that number pull that data cell value from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

For the task that I have been assigned, you are told that when a person enters a number, that data cell value should be pulled from the list. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean "data cell value" as "list item" at an index.

First there is input from the user, using the *input* function.
If this is not a valid integer, the *int* function will raise an exception.

Then we must also check that the index given by the user is within the list size.  The first element of a list is at index #0, and the last is #*list-length* - 1.  For example, a 3-item list has elements at 0, 1, 2.

```
fruit = [ "Apples", "Oranges", "Rambutan", "Mango" ]

try:
    user_text = input("Enter fruit index: ")
    user_choice = int(user_text)
except:
    print("Bad Choice");
    user_choice = -1

if (user_choice >= 0 and user_choice < len(fruit)):
    print("Your Fruit is: " + fruit[user_choice])
else:
    print("Index out of range")
```

E.g.:

```
# python3 ./fruit.py 
Enter fruit index: 2
Your Fruit is: Rambutan

# python3 ./fruit.py 
Enter fruit index: None of your business
Bad Choice
Choice out of range
```

Comment: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @Marissa - You're comparing a string and an integer.  Did you miss the line user_choice = int(user_text), or perhaps did you use "user_text" instead of "user_choice" in the comparison?